# golang functions: parallel execution with return

Tags: go, goroutine

How to make two functions calls `f1(2)` and `f1(1)` execute in parallel so that all the program would execute for 2 seconds not for 3.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// sleeps for `secs` seconds
func f1(secs time.Duration) (result string) {
    fmt.Printf("waiting %V\n", secs)
    time.Sleep(secs * time.Second)
    result = fmt.Sprintf("waited for %d seconds", secs)
    return
}

// prints arg1, arg2
func f2(arg1, arg2 string) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
    fmt.Println(arg2)
}

// this function executes for 3 seconds, because waits a lot
func runNotParallel() {

    out1 := f1(2)
    out2 := f1(1)
    f2(out1, out2)

}

// golang parallel return functions
// todo: make it run so all the function will executes for 2 seconds not for 3
func runParallel() {
    out1 := f1(2)
    out2 := f1(1)
    f2(out1, out2)
}

func main() {
    runNotParallel()
    runParallel()
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WSRwOKvMBz)

I guess I can do it only with channels. Should I redefine function `f1` or I can leave it as is and change only way I call it?

Comment: When using parallel execution to speed-up a program, Amdahl's Law is important and will be one of the factors that determine whether you are successful or just wasting your effort. In Go, concurrency has broader aims than just faster execution. It's important enough to be worth learning about though, so I wish you success.

Comment: @Rick-777 Amdahl’s Law is more about _parallelism_ than _concurrency_: in certain cases where latency is a huge factor (think of I/O-bound operations such as making 100 HTTP requests), concurrency can be a huge improvement.

Comment: Amdahl's law is quite simple and general - it doesn't care about (or even mention) I/o. Nor does it matter about the difference between parallelism and concurrency; these are widely misunderstood terms anyway.

Comment: You can also check this library https://github.com/ddelizia/channelify (I am the author :) )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use chan/goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// sleeps for `secs` seconds
func f1(secs time.Duration) (result string) {
    fmt.Printf("waiting %v\n", secs)
    time.Sleep(secs * time.Second)
    result = fmt.Sprintf("waited for %v seconds", secs)
    return
}

// prints arg1, arg2
func f2(arg1, arg2 string) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
    fmt.Println(arg2)
}

// this function executes for 3 seconds, because waits a lot
func runNotParallel() {
    out1 := f1(2)
    out2 := f1(1)
    f2(out1, out2)

}

// golang parallel return functions
// todo: make it run so all the function will executes for 2 seconds not for 3
func runParallel() {
    out1 := make(chan string)
    out2 := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        out1 <- f1(2)
    }()
    go func() {
        out2 <- f1(1)
    }()
    f2(<-out1, <-out2)
}

func main() {
    runNotParallel()
    runParallel()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/G4RHiq9LJw

Comment: I made a library that can do what you are doing in few lines with reflection. You can check the example https://github.com/ddelizia/channelify. The logic behind is the same but I think I made it easier to use :)

Answer (score 9):

Another way you could do it is using `WaitGroup`

I wrote this utility function to help parallelize a group of functions:

```
import "sync"

// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(copy func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            copy()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

So in your case, we could do this

```
value1 := ""
value2 := ""

func1 := func() {
    value1 = f1(2)
}

func2 = func() {
    value2 = f1(1)
}

Parallelize(func1, func2)

f2(out1, out2)
```

If you wanted to use the Parallelize function, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util

Comment: This is great, can you please explain the code of Parallelize function?

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution without channels but with the missing **f2** synchronization:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// sleeps for `secs` seconds
func f1(secs time.Duration, result *string, sg *sync.WaitGroup) () {
    fmt.Printf("waiting %v\n", secs)
    time.Sleep(secs * time.Second)
    *result = fmt.Sprintf("waited for %d seconds", secs)
    if sg!= nil {
        sg.Done()
    }
    return
}

// prints arg1, arg2
func f2(arg1, arg2 string) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
    fmt.Println(arg2)
}

// this function executes for 3 seconds, because waits a lot
func runNotParallel() {

    var out1, out2 string
    f1(2, &out1, nil)
    f1(1, &out2,nil)
    f2(out1, out2)

}

// golang parallel return functions
// todo: make it run so all the function will executes for 2 seconds not for 3
func runParallel() {
    var sg sync.WaitGroup
    sg.Add(2)
    var out1, out2 string
    go f1(2, &out1, &sg)
    go f1(1, &out2, &sg)
    sg.Wait()
    f2(out1, out2)
}

func main() {
    runNotParallel()
    runParallel()
}
```

basically, **go** operator blocks from using/accessing a return values but it could be done using a pointers for the return place holders in the signature

Answer (score 0):

With go 1.18 supporting generics, the [channel solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27792477/444917) can be made even more readable.

```
func async[T any](f func() T) chan T {
    ch := make(chan T)
    go func() {
        ch <- f()
    }()
    return ch
}

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now().Local()

    out1 := async(func() string {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        return "thing 1"
    })
    out2 := async(func() string {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        return "thing 2"
    })

    results := []string{<-out1, <-out2}

    fmt.Printf("results: %v\n", results)
    fmt.Printf("took %v", time.Since(startTime))
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/e1hhLe74Rbc)

The [lo package](https://github.com/samber/lo) provides this along with lots of other generic helper functions.